# How to overwrite endowed account balance (Build a local blockchain)

Tags: substrate-node-template

I followed [this tutorial](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/get-started/build-local-blockchain/) to build a local blockchain and everything worked fine.

Now I would like to change the account balances for instance 0 for all accounts.

By looking at [this post](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/156/how-to-overwrite-endowed-account-balances-using-additional-accounts-and-balances/355#355), I thought that I just need to modify balances in chain_spec.rs:

```
balances: BalancesConfig {
        // Configure endowed accounts with initial balance of 1 << 60.
        balances: endowed_accounts.iter().cloned().map(|k| (k, 0)).collect(),
    },
```

However it doesn't work and the balance didn't change (still 1<<60 for Alice and Bob). I also tried purging the chain.

How can I modify the initial balances of Alice and Bob ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends how you run your node you have to modify the `testnet_genesis()` function or the `local_testnet_config()`.

To make the balance 0 is as your code (changing the 1 << 60 with 0):

```
balances: BalancesConfig {
        // Configure endowed accounts with initial balance of 1 << 60.
        balances: endowed_accounts.iter().cloned().map(|k| (k, 0)).collect(),
    },
```

This populates the accounts in the `endowed_accounts` list.

To add/remove accounts you have to modify the list you are sending in the parameters when calling one of this functions `testnet_genesis()` function or the `local_testnet_config()`:

```
// Pre-funded accounts
            vec![
                get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Alice"),
                get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Bob"),
                get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Alice//stash"),
                get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Bob//stash"),
            ],
```

After the changes build and run the node again:

```
cargo build --release
cargo run --release -- --dev
```

If you set all the accounts with 0, you will see this error message

```
 'the balance of any account should always be at least the existential deposit.'
```

Be aware you need at least an account with more than the existential depostit, you can modify the `EXISTENTIAL_DEPOSIT` constant in the runtime: `runtime/src/lib.rs`.

Comment: thank you for your detailed answer :)