# Added ROC token on local Rococo account created using cumulus

Tags: cumulus, rococo-local, local

I have Alice, bob and so on accounts created by `cumulus` itself. However, these account's have only `1 MUnit` and I want to add more of them. I already tried !drip in faucet but that account is not added in my `local-rococo` network.

Comment: https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/6056/how-to-overwrite-endowed-account-balance-build-a-local-blockchain

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to overwrite endowed account balance (Build a local blockchain)](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/6056/how-to-overwrite-endowed-account-balance-build-a-local-blockchain)

Comment: I have tried these but none of it works

Answer (score 0):

The faucet won't work because is for a specific chain, in this case for Rococo.

In your cumulus network you have to modify the pre-populate balance for the accounts before run your chain.

You can find an example of how to do this step-by-step here: [How to overwrite endowed account balance (Build a local blockchain)](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/6059/2762)