# Replacing Endowed Account Address in a Local Substrate Blockchain: A Tutorial

Tags: substrate-node-template, substrate-contracts-node, local, dev, dev-node

Hello Substrate community!

If you have been following the tutorial on building a local blockchain using Substrate, you may have noticed that your address is hard-coded in a JSON file.

To replace your address with my address, you can refer to the Substrate documentation on building a local blockchain:
https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/build-a-blockchain/build-local-blockchain/

Please let me know if you have any other suggestions or if you need further assistance.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the question? You want to use your own account instead of Alice, Bob...?

Comment: Hi @Alex Bean 
Thanks for your response,
Yes,I want my own account address instead of Alice,Bob.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you keep going with the tutorials, in this one [Add trusted nodes](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/build-a-blockchain/add-trusted-nodes/) you will see how to generate your own accounts with the tool [SubKey](https://docs.substrate.io/reference/command-line-tools/subkey/)
and how to start the node.

To customize the endowed accounts balances when start your chain you specify this in the `chain_spec.rs`. The chain specification is a source code file that defines a Substrate chain's initial (genesis) state.

Here you can [see an example](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/blob/main/node/src/chain_spec.rs#L57) of the node-template that the tutorial uses.

See this previous StackExchange answer that explains how to do this in detail: [How to overwrite endowed account balances using additional accounts and balances](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/303/2762).

Comment: Hi @Alex Bean,

Good morning! Thanks for response. I followed your reference and added my address to the chain-spec-plain.json file. However, when I ran my project, my address was not displayed in the Polkadot development portal. How can I run my chain-spec-plain.json file? Also, how can I disable the default command?

I used the following command:

./target/release/node-template --base-path /tmp/relay/alice --chain ./chain-spec-plain.json --alice --port 30333 --rpc-cors all --rpc-methods Safe --ws-port 9945 --rpc-port 9933 --validator
Please let me this command is correct?

Comment: First to import your account in the Polkadot development portal see this article: https://support.polkadot.network/support/solutions/articles/65000176241-polkadot-js-ui-how-to-import-a-private-key-from-another-wallet . And see that when running your node you are indicating the flag --alice in your command, see this https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/build-a-blockchain/add-trusted-nodes/ to see how to run your own one.

Comment: Hi @Alex Bean, good afternoon! Thank you for your response. I followed the steps you provided, completed all the steps.added the address to Polkadot. I ran the command, but my address is not showing up in my own development Polkadot.js.how to check my development wallet balance using comments?I following below command
./target/release/node-template --base-path /tmp/node01 --chain ./customSpecRaw.json --port 30333 --ws-port 9945 --rpc-port 9933 --telemetry-url "wss://telemetry.polkadot.io/submit/0" --validator --rpc-methods Unsafe --rpc-cors all --name MyNode01 --password-interactiveThank you.

Comment: Hi @Alex Bean, good afternoon!

how to check my development wallet balance using commands ? please let me know here this is very helpful to me.

thanks in advance,

Comment: You have to import your account in PolkadotJS, importing it directly or with the extension, check the steps here https://support.polkadot.network/support/solutions/articles/65000169952-polkadot-extension-how-to-restore-your-account#:~:text=Open%20the%20Polkadot%20extension%20and,from%20pre%2Dexisting%20seed%22 or here https://docs.cloud.coinbase.com/delegation/docs/polkadot-ui-fund or

Comment: Hi @Alex Bean,
Thanks for your response,